# How to make SSH remote port forward that listens 0.0.0.0

Tags: ssh, portforwarding

I need to do remote port forwarding that will listen `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` on the remote machine so that I can connect from outside internet to `IP_OF_BBB:SOME_PORT` in order to connect to SSH port of `AAA`.

I managed to make this happen by the following:

1. AAA:~$ `ssh -R 22:localhost:2222 user@BBB`
2. BBB:~$ `ssh -L 2222:*:2223 user@localhost`

Now I can connect to `AAA` with this command:

`ssh user@BBB -p 2223`

The local port forwarding is a workaround, of course. Is there any clearer way to do this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Enable `GatewayPorts` in [sshd_config](http://www.openssh.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config) (by default it is disabled). Enabling it will instruct sshd to allow remote port forwardings to bind to a non-loopback address. AskUbuntu has a similar question about [Reverse Port Tunneling that goes into more details](https://askubuntu.com/a/50075).

Comment: use @anton-bessonov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62142365/210475) to avoid having to modify your sshd_config.

Comment: @ZombieDev No, that answer is wrong for the given question. It' valid for local forwarding, not remote.

Comment: The option `GatewayPorts` is not supported in dropbear.

Answer (score 21):

As addition to the existing answer you can use `ssh -o GatewayPorts=true -L 2222:0.0.0.0:2223 user@localhost`

Comment: The `-o` flag was not working for me. The question above worked.

Comment: Same for me, using the `-o` flag didn't work and the connection was still bound to localhost, enabling the `GatewayPorts` option in the config worked without any issues.

Comment: `-o GatewayPorts=true` seems not work with `-R` option (listen on remote)

Comment: Where are you supposed to run `ssh -o GatewayPorts=true -L 2222:0.0.0.0:2223 user@localhost`? On the remote or the local machine?

Answer (score 3):

Not a SSH way, but why not use a socat trick on your remote host?

```
# this clones localhost:3129 to 0.0.0.0:3130
socat TCP-LISTEN:3130,fork,bind=0.0.0.0 TCP:localhost:3129
```

If you don't have socat yet simply install as:

```
apt update; apt install -y socat
```

Comment: Disadvantage (and possible root of conflictions): That way you are occupying 1 more port per application.

Comment: umm, yes. It's a workaround when the `-o GatewayPorts=true` on `-R` doesn't work.

Comment: 1. no root permissions 2. local address not accessible from server due to NAT etc

Answer (score -3):

BBB :ssh command should be:

```
BBB:~$ ssh -L 2223:*:2222 user@localhost
```